# How to change the content of text in an Arcade window?

Tags: python, arcade

I am currently trying to create a text that can be updated whenever I hit a button. After going through the documentation, I saw the `arcade.draw_text` function is returning a `text_sprite` object, but it seems unable to change the text of that object.

Am I doing it completely the wrong way? Or there is a trick I did not get into yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Following script changes text on mouse click:

```
import arcade

class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(600, 400)
        self.text = 'Waiting for click...'

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        arcade.draw_text(self.text, 300, 200, arcade.color.RED, 30, anchor_x='center')

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, key_modifiers):
        self.text = 'Clicked!'

MyGame()
arcade.run()
```

Text before click:

[image]

Text after click:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to accept your great reply!

Comment: With the new arcade object-oriented text, you can create it in the init function, draw it in the on_draw method, and you can change its .text property to the desired text. This is from 50-100 times faster than the draw_text method.